# Adjust filters on a site and change results with javascript in the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I am working with Ticketmaster.com and I would like to write javascript code in the console to make changes to the ticket results.

I am working on this webpage: https://www.ticketmaster.com/utah-jazz-vs-phoenix-suns/event/1E005B1208CD3AFA?refArtist=K8vZ9171o5V

I want to be able to change the number of tickets by changing the dropdown in the screenshot below

[image]

I also want to change the results to include fees by changing the fees filter found by clicking "Filters" as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

And then checking the fees checkbox and clicking "Apply Filters"

[image]

I can use this code to change the value of the  list to change the number of tickets but it does not change the ticket results.

```
 var select = document.getElementById('filter-bar-quantity');
 select.options[2].selected = "selected"
```

---

How can I change the filter parameters of number of tickets and including fees to change the results from the console using javascript? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: ok, but why via devtools?

Comment: @IamL because a webscraping application I am using needs it in javascript and this is the way that I was working with it. open to suggestions but need the answer to be with javascript injection/execution